# How to find the device is connected to whether USB port 2.0 or USB port 3.00 ?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I just want to know how to find a usb device is connected to USB3.0 or USB2.0 port in window . I am using c++ and win32 API. please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: 1. Find out which port the device is connected to. 2. Find out whether that is a USB 3 port or not. I bet that these are two distinct issues. I also bet that you will find questions covering both if you search.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how your question is phrased, I assume that you know when a device is connected, and need to know if the port it's connected is capable of USB 3.0 speeds.

Take a look at the [`USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540094(v=vs.85).aspx) structure, and specifically the field Speed in it, which could correspond to a value defined in the enum [`USB_DEVICE_SPEED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539294(v=vs.85).aspx). For USB 3.0, the value of Speed would be `UsbSuperSpeed`.

The [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540094(v=vs.85).aspx) says that you could use [`IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537321(v=vs.85).aspx) request to obtain information about the connection associated with the indicated USB port.

You may also find the following remarks from the documentation helpful:

1. If there is no device connected, `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX` just returns information about the port.
2. If a device is connected to the port `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX` returns information about **both the port and the connected device**.
3. The `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX` structure is an extended version of `USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION`. The two structures are identical, except for one member. In the extended structure, the Speed member indicates the device speed.

I'd also encourage you to single-step through the [usbview](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) project which is part of the windows driver samples available in Github.